# How to create reusable template Angular?

Tags: angular

I have array of objects:

```
let arr = [{id: 1, values: []}, {id: 2, values: []}, {id: 3, values: []}]
```

I need to show values under each row in separate template:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of arr">
   <div *ngIf="row.values.length"><ng-template [values]="row.values"></ng-template></div>
   <div class="hidden">This should be showen by click element above</div>
</div>


<ng-template [values]="values">
    <div class="list">
       <div *ngFor="let item of values">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

So, I have tried to pass array `values` to template and display it inside template. How to do that this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to user ngTemplateOutlet to render the ng-template and you can pass the data by set context

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of arr">
   <div *ngIf="row.values.length">
       <ng-container 
             *ngTemplateOutlet="valuesTem;context: {$implicit: row.values} ">
       </ng-container>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden">This should be showen by click element above</div>
</div>


<ng-template let-values #valuesTem >
    <div class="list"> 
       <div *ngFor="let item of values">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

> [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gybx2b?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you, could I use another tewmplate inside `<ng-template let-values #valuesTem >`? To show/hide by click `{{item}}`?